# Quantum GIS Garmin Maps62 device and GPS utility - making a polygon for random point

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, garmin

I have a Garmin GPSMaps62 unit and GPS utility. I have logged tracks and need to get these to load as polygon layers in Quantum so that I can then ask Q to give me random sample points and upload these back to the unit and use the find option. Any help in simple steps (I am learning) would be fantastic please. I am particularly struggling with getting the tracks downloaded to quantum via GPS utility to show as polygon layers.

Answer (score 2):

Since your track is NOT a polygon, but rather a line, I think there's no way around manually editing the line to snap the endpoints to the exact same location. So:

Once you're downloaded the gpx file from the GPS, do "Save As..." to save it as a shapefile.
Now load that shapefile, and start editing. Be sure snapping is setup correctly (Settings-> Snapping options), and move the last node of the line so that it snaps to the first. Save your edits and quit editing.
Now in the Vector->Geometry Tools, use "Line to Polygon" to create a polygon feature of the closed boundary.

### HTH

Micha

Comment: Thank you very much; That makes sense and I will give that a go and see how I get on. Best wishes, Justin

Comment: OK, Micha's answer brilliant and now have a polygon and have succesfully raised 25 random sample points and saved as a shape file. I have checked that GPS utility and the shape file are set at 27700 BNG but when I try and open the sample points shape file in GPS utility it says cannot open shape file. Can anybody help and is there an easy solution as I need to sample these points soon!